# Shrink and Resize LVM right approach?

Tags: partition

I'm interested to learn how to resize an existing LVM partition and allocate some space to another LVM partition.

First I run:

```
[root@ ~]# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1]
md2 : active raid1 sda2[0] sdb2[1]
20478912 blocks [2/2] [UU]
md3 : active raid1 sdb3[1] sda3[0]
1931981760 blocks [2/2] [UU]
bitmap: 3/15 pages [12KB], 65536KB chunk
unused devices: <none>  

[root@ ~]# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
 /dev/md2         20G   14G  4.2G  77% /
 devtmpfs         16G     0   16G   0% /dev
 tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /dev/shm
 tmpfs            16G   43M   16G   1% /run
 tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
 /dev/sda1       510M  3.5M  507M   1% /boot/efi
 /dev/md3        1.8T   37G  1.7T   3% /home
 /dev/loop0      592M   53M  508M  10% /tmp
 tmpfs           3.2G     0  3.2G   0% /run/user/0

[root@ ~]# cat /proc/partitions
major minor  #blocks  name
8        0 1953514584 sda
8        1     523264 sda1
8        2   20478976 sda2
8        3 1931981824 sda3
8        4     523264 sda4
8       16 1953514584 sdb
8       17     523264 sdb1
8       18   20478976 sdb2
8       19 1931981824 sdb3
8       20     523264 sdb4
9        3 1931981760 md3
9        2   20478912 md2
7        0     631808 loop0`
```

Now, what i think I should do first, **Shrink** A Logical Volume:

```
lvresize --resizefs --size 1948G /dev/md3
lvresize --resizefs --size -80G /dev/md3
```

Then, resize it:

```
lvresize --size -80G /dev/md3
lvresize --size +80G /dev/md2
```

Do you think this is correct approach?

Comment: Welcome to U&L! 1) You don't seem to have any LVM volumes there. `/dev/md2` as `/dev/md3` appear to be MD RAID devices. What do `pvdisplay` / `vgdisplay` / `lvdisplay` tell you? 2) One `resize` per volume is enough. Not sure why you want to execute three commands on `/dev/md3`. Just resize the one you want to shrink first, and then the one  you want to grow.

Comment: Hi, pvdisplay/vgdisplay/lvdisplay return empty.

Comment: Then, since you are not using LVM, you might want to edit your question, depending on what you are trying to do.

Comment: OK, thank you. I'll try to edit my question if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach won't work because you are not using LVM at all.

Resizing mdadm raid is not trivial, not recommended unless you really know what you're doing.

That said, 20G should be plenty for `/` on most desktop systems.

Maybe check what is using the most of the space and then outsource something to your `/home` partition (using a symlink or whatever).

```
mkdir /mnt/root
mount --bind / /mnt/root
ncdu /mnt/root
```

For example if there is a `/var/www` or `/opt/game` that could be relocated to `/home/somewhere` without doing any filesystem resize at all.

```
mkdir /home/www
rsync -a /var/www/. /home/www/.
mv /var/www /var/www-old
ln -s ../home/www /var/www
```

Test if everything still works, then eventually delete `/var/www-old`.

Comment: The reason that / was increasing, because I've activated Backups from WHM, and i did't notice its using /backup.

Comment: But i still want to increase ' /dev/md2 '